# Weird linker error linking to opencv... "LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2E8"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

This OpenCV build was working for me a few nights ago.  I am trying to run the example `grabcut.cpp` file given with the OpenCV examples and so I set up a quick project and brough the `cpp` file in.  Then, I set up all of the standard configurations and got this error on building.

> ```
> error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2E8   
> opencv_calib3d231.dll
> ```

What does this mean?

Comment: directly related: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h6ctxtk.aspx

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If I would have to guess (partially based on [the documentation of that error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h6ctxtk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)), I'd say you're trying to link directly against the DLL.

You probably want to link against its corresponding .lib file.

Comment: I feel like I always linked against DLLs before... That's not normal?

Comment: Depends on the compiler; MinGW, for example, seems to be able to directly link against DLLs.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know about MinGW. Perhaps you're right. It might do something similar as one could do with Visual Studio's tools to generate a .def and thereby a .lib from a DLL. However (unless anyone can tell me otherwise) I don't think Visual Studio allows for direct linking against a DLL. You either have to use a .lib or dynamically load the DLL in your code.

Comment: make sure you are linking `.lib` file instead `.dll`

Comment: Another common case of this exact error is when accidentally missing the `-o` flag, thus mistakenly specifying a binary as a source file.