# How do you import external symbols when compiling the C sources of an R package?

Tags: r

I have downloaded the source code of an R package, "stats" in this case,
and would like to compile the C code of a function in there.
So far, *compilation* in the narrower sense seems to work, but the linker needs to import some symbols from
external libraries, e.g. "R_BaseEnv", defined by

> #define LibImport __declspec(dllimport)
>
> #define LibExtern extern LibImport
>
> LibExtern SEXP  R_BaseEnv;       /* The base environment; formerly R_NilValue */

Among the downloaded files are some .dll-files, e.g. "R.dll",
but I have learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657040/weird-linker-error-linking-to-opencv-lnk1107-invalid-or-corrupt-file-canno) that the linker needs the corresponding .lib-files.
So how can I get the .lib-files? Searching for "R.lib" was without result.